# why there is a left join and right join in MySQl?

Tags: mysql, sql

I think either left/right join is sufficient, the other will derived if table names are interchanged, Anyone know why there is both left and right join?
Thanks

Comment: Agree with the above comment, and read Gordon's answer which states that right join isn't really needed at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of join evaluation is generally left-to-right. So `a join b join c` executes as if you had parenthesized it `(a join b) join c`.

The optimizer can reorder inner joins because inner joins are commutative. Reordering outer joins is not commutative (i.e. `a left join b` is not the same as `b left join a)`, so the optimizer can't swap them.

If you want to do a left outer join to the result of a joined pair of tables, use parentheses, like: `a left join (b join c)`.

But you can also take advantage of the left-to-right order of evaluation by switching to a right outer join: `b join c right outer join a` -- without parentheses!